# Limit Request Per Second for API

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlets, httprequest

How can i limit Request per second for the any API we are developing.
I need to limit request per second on the basis of token we provide for each client.
So lets say if i have TOKEN1 provided to our client which comes in the request header and we have limited request per second 10 for that token then Client can only access 10 time per second our API. Whether they access for any number of computers if they use same token they can only access 10 request per second.
How can this be achieved using Spring Boot?
We have Spring Boot Application.

Answer (score 2):

There are some (maven) packages for standard throttling available, e.g.: https://github.com/weddini/spring-boot-throttling.

The example code looks like that:

```
@Throttling(type = ThrottlingType.HeaderValue, headerName = "X-Forwarded-For", limit = 10, timeUnit = TimeUnit.HOURS)
public void serviceMethod() {
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer i will look into that one
This is the third party library but if spring provide this type of built in support ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn‘t. ;)

Comment: @dersvenhesse this example use jar file , which could not found central repository ........do you know, why?

Comment: @panthaistiaque you need to add the repository, like described under "Maven setup": https://github.com/weddini/spring-boot-throttling